# Get an array value into a variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have an array and I want to get the value 233 into a variable that I can use.

print_r($myVar) returns:

```
Array(
  [folders] => Array(
    [0] => Array(
      [project] => 233
    )
  )
) 1
```

How do I get the value 233 into a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is in an array, you can use it like this:

```
echo $myVar['folders'][0]['project'];
```

If you want to copy it into another variable, it is very much similar:

```
$var = $myVar['folders'][0]['project'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$var = $arrayname["folders"][0]["project"];`

Should store the number 233 in the `$var` veriable.

- just be sure to change `arrayname` into the array name.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$value = $my_array["folders"][0]["project"]
```

you can echo this('$value') to get "233"